# Strange behavior of Flash in Firefox (looks like multithreading!)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, firefox

Recently I've noticed that my application stated failing in FireFox 6 (works ok in Chrome) with following stack trace:

```
Error: Error #2058: There was an error decompressing the data.
    at flash.utils::ByteArray/_uncompress()
    at flash.utils::ByteArray/uncompress()
    at com.***.client::SocketProtocol/onSocketData()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_evalJS()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()
    at com.***.client.utils::Browser$/openNewWindow()
    at com.***.client::XpraClient/newWindowHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at com.***.client.xpra::Protocol/processMessage()
    at com.***.client.xpra::SocketProtocol/onSocketData()
```

This stack trace suggests that SocketProtocol.onSocketData (which is an event handler for ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA event of a Socket) is fired *before* previous handler completes.

Is there a way to further diagnose/debug this problem? Is there any specifics in how recent versions of FireFox handle Flash?

**UPDATE**: This only happens in FireFox 6. Previous versions of FireFox work fine.

Comment: instead of trace, make some Loader.load ( 'with trace statements' ). and the upload stuff online and launch it. usualy i do it like that when i need to debug in browser. if anyone has a better solution please share.

Comment: I have my internal traces and they basically confirm that onSocketData() is called before previous onSocketData() completes, which should not happen.

Comment: do you use any type of JS? because i got some problems with Safari on MacOS. when i was using SwfAddress, somehow after one call in about 1 - 1.5 seconds i got the second same call. and my content was reloading. event it already was the same. might be that there are more issues like this. i solved my problem by checking if the call was received with the same name as i'm receiving again -> do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what's going on based on just a stack trace, but I notice you're using `ExternalInterface`.  `ExternalInterface` can introduce intermittent problems when called synchronously in conjunction with other communication interactions.  I recommend you try using `setTimeout` with a delay of 0 msec to make your `ExternalInterface` call asynchronous.